# Samsung tablet a8 screen touch unresponsive

Tags: touchscreen, samsung-galaxy-tab

I have samsung galaxy tab a8 still new and I faced an issue with the touch screen it's unresponsive totally, I tried to soft reset with pressing the power button and volume down till restart and the Samsung logo appears but still not working.
Anyone knows what to do for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the touch screen is not working,  you can't use it  you need to get it looked at.

If its new take it to Samsung under warranty.

It can be

1. Manufacturing fault
2. Digitizer for the screen has gone faulty
3. Drops or vibrations could have dislodged a connector